# Get Intent's content (Android)

Tags: android, android-intent

I Would like to get the content of an Intent, for example:

```
 AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null,null,null,false,null,null,null,null)
```

gives an Intent object which presents a dialog with a list of the device's accounts.

How can I access the list that the Intent presents?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read contacts or any other things, you should directly request for it. these kind of Intents are pre-built by google. you CAN'T pull their data out.
I don't know exactly what you are looking for, but check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42918731/get-list-of-accounts-in-android).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I mentioned this Intent as an example, I want to know if there is a way to get the Intent's content, for example the list mentioned earlier.

Comment: @Geekybean you want intent with it's data ? or just data only?

Comment: the data only (not in getExtra)

Comment: @Geekybean ,You cannot achieve that by using intents. you need to directly request for data only. i need to know what you are looking for if you want a straight answer from me